Glide: Load local SVG file into ImageView
I have a local SVG file that I want to load into my image view. The SVG file is provided to my app thru our integration mechanism in the company. In other words, I cannot get the SVG file thru the form of URL. I am using Glide to load the image but could not make it work. Here is my setup
This is my dependency:
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'

This is my permission:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

And here is my source code:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    File imageFile = // i get an instance of SVG file from our integration module
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    Glide.with(this).load(imageFile .toURI()).into(imageView);
}

And finally, the error:

Cause (1 of 1): class
com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to
find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class java.net.URI
2024-05-13 23:22:41.654
23538-23538/com.sample.app I/Glide: Root cause
(1 of 1)
com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders registered for model class: class
java.net.URI

EDIT:
I tried what was discussed in here but still got error. This is my resulting code:
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    File imageFile = // i get an instance of SVG file from our integration module
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    Glide.with(this).load(imageFile).into(imageView);
}

And this is the resulting error:

2024-05-13 23:39:38.605
26958-26958/com.sample.app W/Glide: Load failed
for
[/data/data/com.sample.app/files/parameters/sample.svg]
with dimensions [720x1102]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There were 2 root causes:
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
java.lang.RuntimeException(setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000)
call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
LoadPath{DirectByteBuffer->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->GifDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->Bitmap->BitmapDrawable}
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
DecodePath{DirectByteBuffer->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
LoadPath{FileInputStream->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL
Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
DecodePath{FileInputStream->GifDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->BitmapDrawable}
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
DecodePath{FileInputStream->BitmapDrawable->Drawable}
Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed
LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Object->Drawable}, LOCAL


See also the Glide documentation, which shows that there is a version of load() that takes a File.

@CommonsWare The linked solution did not solve my issue. I updated the question.

The current Glide documentation doesn't mention a native SVG import/loading method. From the error logs it seems like you're loading SVG (xml/vector) with a method expecting a raster (bitmap) image binary data chunk . Otherwise you could probably convert your SVG to a android drawable beforehand. This SO post may be helpful "How to load svg image to image view using Glide"

This solved my issue.
app/build.gradle:
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
implementation("com.caverock:androidsvg:1.4")

Java code:
File imageFile = // i get an instance of SVG file from our integration module
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
try {
    SVG svg = SVG.getFromInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
    Drawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(svg.renderToPicture());
    Glide.with(this).load(drawable).into(imageView);
} catch (SVGParseException | FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

